# Добавление данных в спискок при условии

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется список:

```py
mylist = [(1, 6), (2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1), (6, 2), (8, 2)]
```

Как можно добавить отсутствующий элемент в таком условии: предполагается что первое число это индекс, следовательно отсутствуют данные с индексом 4 и 7. Всего должно быть 8 элементов в списке. Как автоматизировать, что то не могу понять. На выходе должно получиться вот так:

```py
mylist = [(1, 6), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 2), (7, 0), (8, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
mylist = [(1, 6), (2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1), (6, 2), (8, 2)]

for i in range(8):
    try:
        k = mylist[i][0]
        if k - 1 != i:
            mylist.insert(i, (i + 1, 0))
    except IndexError:
        mylist.insert(i, (i + 1, 0))

print(mylist)
```

***stdout:***

```py
[(1, 6), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 2), (7, 0), (8, 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [(1, 6), (2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1), (6, 2), (8, 2)]

res = dict(mylist)
[res.setdefault(x,0) for x in range(min(mylist)[0],max(mylist)[0])]
lst = sorted([(k, v) for k, v in res.items()])
print(lst)
```

Результат:

```
[(1, 6), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 2), (7, 0), (8, 2)]
```